# failure, error when running office 2007 under wine

Tags: 12.04, unity, wine, microsoft-office

i am trying to run office 2007 using wine , everything installed fine but when i try to open any file using word,excel i get DDE failure , or an exception please refer to attached screen shot [image: screen shot shows the error while i running office word or excel]

Comment: Can you please crop your screen shot to target only the error messages. I can't read them, Thanks.

Comment: done , please let me know if there is a way to fix this error

Comment: A couple of follow up questions. Ubuntu Version? and Wine Version?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , wine 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen alot of **assertion failed** errors over the years (mainly in native Windows) and they are quite hard to pin point. I recommend that you uninstall Office then upgrade your Wine version as per the instruction below and lastly try installing Office again.

First add the add the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Then update your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try installing Wine 1.5

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

That should get you up and running.

**References**

[Adding the WineHQ PPA Repository](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

Comment: more very important details here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992